# What is the tikkun for a unmarried Jewish man that slept with a non Jewish woman with protection?

Tags: sexuality, repentance-teshuvah, intermarriage

[Chabad.org org quotes](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/148995/jewish/On-Intermarriage.htm):

> (Deut. 7:3): "You shall not marry them (the gentiles, about which the
>   Bible speaks in the previous verses), you shall not give your daughter
>   to their son and you shall not take his daughter for your son."

If a single Jewish man erred and slept with a single Gentile woman (using contraception), what is his rectification for this sin?

Comment: http://www.din.org.il/2015/01/01/%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%9D-%D7%92%D7%95%D7%99%D7%94/

Comment: English please.

Comment: 1) Regret that he did it. 2) Stop doing it. 3) Ask forgiveness from anyone harmed (if applicable). 4) Confess to God (Vidui). 5) Accept never to do it again. (All that done seriously, not just lip-service.)

Comment: It seems no different then the other sins. Wasn't this item one of the big ones in the Zohar that cannot be forgiven or something?

Comment: @bibi987 No such thing. Anyone who does the step above seriously will be forgiven. (Sometimes doing so is very, very hard though.)

Comment: I remember hearing that some sins are more difficult to rectify than others - and I believe this one was one of them. You sure there aren't any additional measures that must be taken?

Answer (score 4):

[Shaar Ruach Hakodesh Tikun Avonos - page 54 - Rabbi Chaim Vital](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14179&st=&pgnum=50&hilite=) says the Teshuva for such a sin is Tevila in snow 7 or 9 times. I do not how this is done. However Hashem always accepts sincere Teshuva which includes not doing it again, regretting the sin, confessing.

Answer (score -4):

The same tikkun as any other pre-marital or extra marital sex. Sleeping with a gentile is not a biblical prohibition, it's a rabbinic one.

Because if the following interpretation of the verse is true:

> (Deut. 7:3): "You shall not marry them (the gentiles, about which the
>   Bible speaks in the previous verses), you shall not give your daughter
>   to their son and you shall not take his daughter for your son.

then this verse means to not marry any gentile, but this also means that you are obligated to kill every gentile you meet. Why? Because the previous verse says the following:

> (Deut 7:2): " and when the LORD thy God shall deliver them up before thee, and thou shalt smite them; then thou shalt utterly destroy them; thou shalt make no covenant with them, nor show mercy unto them;"

You cannot cut this verse both ways. You can't say it's talking about inter-marrying with any and all gentiles, and then switch and say the commandment to kill these same gentiles doesn't apply in the same way. The only way to interpret this with any kind of sense is to take it in the proper context, which would be Deut 7:1

> (Deut 7:1): "When the LORD thy God shall bring thee into the land whither thou goest to possess it, and shall cast out many nations before thee, the Hittite, and the Girgashite, and the Amorite, and the Canaanite, and the Perizzite, and the Hivite, and the Jebusite, seven nations greater and mightier than thou;"

You are not allowed to intermarry with the specific 7 Canaanite nations. So if by the off chance you happened to sleep with a Jebusite then yeah that would be a pretty grievous sin, almost as grievous as not murdering her [sarcasm].

Comment: Oy! If only the Rambam had read the surrounding verses he may not have made that mistake! Goes to show...

Comment: Yeah i know he rules that it's a miswah d'oraita. But if disagreeing with the Rambam were a sin then the Shulchan Arukh would be blasphemous :D Speaking of, i think the Rambam is siding with the Talmud which renders that it's a prohibition, and so he has to provide a proof, and that's the closest [Torah] scripture you can get for the prohibition of intermarriage with gentiles. Clearly Ezra and the leaders of his time took on the prohibition against intermarriage though.

Comment: Disagreeing with the Rambam is not a sin. Disagreeing with all of traditional Talmudic Judaism based on the claim that they didn't notice the simple reading of the adjacent verse is pretty blasphemous in that it accuses them all of being bumbling buffoons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23970/discussion-between-aaron-and-double-aa).